# statscm alternative

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-scm

Is there an alternative to the maven plugin statscm? http://stat-scm.sourceforge.net/

Looking for something that has active development. Also there are some lingering bugs which are only available in the Snapshot. Though Maven doesn't allow Snapshot versions in a released artifact so unable to use the snapshot statscm with bugfixes

Comment: Error received [INFO] Feb 1, 2011 3:41:31 PM net.sf.statsvn.util.JavaUtilTaskLogger info
[INFO] INFO: Using default CSS file (statcvs.css)
[INFO] Feb 1, 2011 3:41:31 PM net.sf.statsvn.util.JavaUtilTaskLogger error
[INFO] SEVERE: The repository object is not valid. Please check your settings.
[INFO] Is the log file empty? Do you run from a checked out directory? Do you ha
ve non-committed items?
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] 
[INFO] Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this one?